# plotting in a loop by indexing column max and min value in add_series

Tags: python, pandas, loops, xlsxwriter

I am trying to plot a bar chart using `xlsxwriter`, but I have a list of dataframe and want to draw a bar chart for each dataframe using a loop. So I need to `add_series` with `values` and `categories` with each dataframe, which has different sizes, how can I read each dataframe and index the max and min column for each dataframe?

```
# open an excel
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_charts.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

for i in list(df_list):
    df = df_list[i]
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=i, index=False)

    workbook = writer.book
    worksheet = writer.sheets[i]

    ## add bar chart in each sheet
    chart = workbook.add_chart({'type':'bar'})

    ## what should I replace '!B$2:$B$8' and '!A$2:$A$8'?
    chart.add_series({'values':'=' + i + '!B$2:$B$8',
                      'categories':'=' + i + '!A$2:$A$8'
                     })
    worksheet.insert_chart('D1', chart)

writer.save()
```

Thanks!

Comment: `for i in list(df_list)`, that means `i` is already an element of `df_list`, so you almost certainly can't do `df_list[i]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most XlsxWriter APIs support both a `A1` style range or `(row, col)` style set of values. This also applies to [chart.add_series()](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/chart.html#chart-add-series)

```py
chart.add_series({
    'categories': '=Sheet1!$A$1:$A$5',
    'values':     '=Sheet1!$B$1:$B$5',
})

# Or using a list of values instead of category/value formulas:
#     [sheetname, first_row, first_col, last_row, last_col]
chart.add_series({
    'categories': ['Sheet1', 0, 0, 4, 0],
    'values':     ['Sheet1', 0, 1, 4, 1],
})
```

Therefor in your example you could do something like this:

```py
sheet_name = i  # Or str(i)

row_min = 1
row_max = len(df) + 1
col_min = 0
col_max = 1

chart.add_series({
    'categories': [sheet_name, row_min, col_min, row_max, col_min],
    'values':     [sheet_name, row_min, col_max, row_max, col_max],
})
```

See also [this Pandas chart example](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_pandas_chart_line.html) from the XlsxWriter docs.

Comment: And OP can you use the tuple output of pandas' [`DateFrame.shape`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shape.html) to retrieve row and column max.

Comment: Yes that would work too. Note, the max column would only need to change if they were iterating over each column and and adding a new series, which is probably not the case here, but worth pointing out for more general solutions.